# Coded UI - Single datasource for multiple testmethods

Tags: datasource, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

So, I have say 3 TestMethods. I attach the same datasource to each, then run with 5 rows of data. I get 5 iterations of TM #1 followed by 5 of TM #2 followed by 5 of TM #3.

```
11111 22222 33333
```

What I'd prefer is to have is an iteration of all 3 TMs, followed by another etc.

```
123 123 123 123 123
```

I know you're not supposed to have dependencies among test methods, but the fact of the matter is that it's a workflow-driven application, and their are dependencies among operations. Can't do 2 until you've done 1, can't do 3 until you've done 2. Once you've done 1, you can't do it again. etc.

`11111, 22222, 33333` works, when all goes well, and is appropriate for some test cases, but doesn't realistically reflect the way the app is used. And when it doesn't work, it can burn up a lot of data that we can't re-use and so end up having to generate new.

Diligently reading help and Googling like a fool has not produced any useful guidance on how... or even whether... this can be done.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping them in to one test case and add data source to it.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSoruce XXXXXXX]
public void OuterTest()
{
        Scenario1();

        Scenario2();

        Scenario3();   

}

private void Scenario1()
{
     // Do your Stuff
}

private void Scenario2()
{
     // Do your stuff
}

private void Scenario3()
{
     // Do your stuff
}
```

then you will have iteration like 123 123 123 123 123